# why the image doesn't follow mousemove

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

I tried many times to find out where is the problem and I can't
I followed the instructor his code was running and my code is the same but doesn't run

```js
var move = document.getElementById('move')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    move.style.left = e.clientX
    move.style.top = e.clientY

})
```

```html
<img id="move" src="img.jpg" alt="PIC" />
```

Comment: The most of the style values need an unit to work, `clientX/Y` returns a plain number without an unit. Also, the image must not be statically positioned.

Comment: Position of your image should be `absolute` or `fixed`. Is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Image should be either `absolute` or `fixed`

**2)** `e.clientX` and `e.clientY` will give you data without any unit. So you've to add any unit. I've added `px` here

```js
var move = document.getElementById('move')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  move.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
  move.style.top = e.clientY + "px";

})
```

```css
img {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<img id="move" src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" alt="PIC" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot include the style for your image...
Anyhow, you also need specify what type of units you are using (`px`)

```js
var move = document.getElementById('move')

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    move.style.left = e.clientX + "px";
    move.style.top = e.clientY + "px";

})
```

```css
#move
{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img id="move" src="img.jpg" alt="PIC" />
```

Comment: You gave me a very useful answer and It worked THNX a lot

Answer (score 0):

Everything's ok in your code. just make image's position as fixed/absolute and must use any type of unit(px,pt,em)

Comment: It would be easier to understand if you can add code and show what exactly do you mean 

Comment: Their code would not work even with position fixed/absolute, because they don't specify the type of units for left/top coordinates.